# How to set up binding for an array with Gwittir and GWT?

Tags: gwt

I have an list of checkboxes on a GWT widget using [Gwittir](http://code.google.com/p/gwittir/).  I want to bind these checkbox values in my view to some values in my Model so that I can tell which ones are selected.  How can I set up a binding to do this?

For a single value (one not in an array), I've been doing this:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.getChildren().add(
     new Binding(viewObj.getTextBox(),"value",modelObj,"textValue"));
```

But I don't know how to transition this to work for an array of items.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using Gwittir for those parts which dealt with arrays of data.  Instead I manually transferred the data from my view to my controller when the user clicked a button which would record the state of all the checkboxes in an array to an array of values in the controller.